# MediaCapture failing intermittently (RecordState - The op is invalid)

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm using `MediaCapture` API to record audio in my Windows Phone 8.1 RT app. The audio recording works fine, but the API intermittently throws `System.Exception` with the following message:
`RecordState System.Exception: The op is invalid.` at the statement
`Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(MediaEncodingProfile encodingProfile, IStorageFile file)`

I haven't been able to find more about this error cause. Can anyone point in some direction?

Comment: Please provide the code that you're using to call the method "StartRecord.." .. Are you using `await` keyword ? This may help you : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6f5fe0ea-293d-4dff-9e6c-1012e35b594a/canot-using-mediacapture-to-record-a-mp4-file-from-camera?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: Found the cause behind this. Multitple calls to `MediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync()` without calling `MediaCapture.StopRecordAsync()` before that throws the Exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the reason for this exception. I was calling `MediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync()` repeatedly, even when the `MediaCapture` object was already recording audio. I had to make sure I call `MediaCapture.StopRecordAsync()` before calling `StartRecordToStorageFileAsync()` so that the state of the recording object is not violated.

Similarly, multiple calls to `StopRecordAsync()` would throw a similar exception.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem, as you said calling multiple times `StartRecordToStorageFileAsync()` without stopping the previous captures with `StopRecordAsync()` produces this situation. I had to make sure I was not triggering `StartRecordToStorageFileAsync()`everytime the timer I was using was activated, I used this:

```
            if (_PrimeraVez)
            {
                CameraRecord(); //My own method
                _PrimeraVez = false;
            }
```

Glad you found the solution yourself.